J5 subform field with 100s of rows - how to paginate?
Using a subform field type on a component item edit view I may have 100s of rows with repeatable table layout.
Is there a way to add pagination to the table?
And also is there a way to provide a search on the subform table to enable the user to jump to a specific item in the list to edit or remove or move or insert after it?
And while I'm about it I'd also like the user to be able to change the sort order on the table.
I fear this might be beyond the capacity of the subform field, but has anyone got any alternative suggestions.
For context I have a table of music tracks, and a table of playlists and a many-many joining table of playlists-tracks. A playlist might have 100+ tracks and using a subform to manage them is getting cumbersome. The admin needs to be able to reorder and insert/delete tracks in the list.

Sounds like the admin back-end functionality for managing eg articles in com_content. Can you take a similar approach to that?
